# Javascript, Calling functions from another onclick in object constructor

Tags: javascript

I need help calling the `this.load` function from inside the `thediv.onclick`. I stripped out most of the code so its really basic, but I really can't find a way to do it. Here is what I currently have:

```
function CreatePizza(Name, Toppings) {
  this.n = Name;
  this.t = Toppings;
  this.load = function loadpizza() {
    //function that i want to be called
  }

  this.create = function button() {
    var thediv = document.createElement("div");
    thediv.onclick = function() {
      // Call this.load function here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just call `this.load()` inside of the `thediv.onclick` function?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst because the function gets it's own context, the `this` value will have changed. Simply assign it to a variable and call it from that variable.

Comment: @somethinghere I know - I wanted OP to show us he was trying so he could learn :)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Sorry about that then, but to be honest, if you read your comment again it does sound an awful lot like a genuine question and not a `brain-teaser` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `onclick` handler, `this` will refer to the `<div>`, not the other `this` which you refer to repeatedly.

Two possible solutions:

1. Save a reference to your desired `this`:

   ```
   that = this;
   thediv.onclick = function () {
      that.load()
   };
   ```
2. Bind `this` to your function:

   ```
   thediv.onclick = function () {
       this.load();
   }.bind(this);
   ```

   Or, if that's the only thing you're doing in that function anyway:

   ```
   thediv.onclick = this.load.bind(this);
   ```

Comment: Good answer for showing *both* of the two main ways to solve this common problem.

Comment: Good answer, I forgot about the binding here. It wasn't immediatly the issue, but I guess it's next on the list after solving this :)

Comment: Thank you so much, really nice awnser!

Answer (score 2):

Because of closures, you can simply assign `this` to a variable and call it from that!

```js
function CreatePizza(Name, Toppings) {
  var self = this;
  this.n = Name;
  this.t = Toppings;
  this.load = function loadpizza() {
    //function that i want to be called
  }
  this.create = function button() {
    var thediv = document.createElement("div");
    thediv.onclick = function() {
      self.load();
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to mention that a nicer - and not necessarily better, before anyone starts a flamewar - way to attach events to your div (and more elegant in my opinion) is to use `thediv.addEventListener('click', self.load, false)`. Just a side-note, though.

Answer (score 1):

Backup the `this` object before binding the event.

```
this.create = function button() {
    var that = this,
        thediv = document.createElement("div");

    thediv.onclick = function() {
        // Call this.load function here
        that.load();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreatePizza(Name, Toppings) {
  this.n = Name;
  this.t = Toppings;

  var foo = function loadpizza() {
    //function that i want to be called
  };


  this.load = foo;
  this.create = function button() {
    var thediv = document.createElement("div");
    thediv.onclick = function() {
      foo();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `this.load = foo` and not `foo()` as that will call your function.

Comment: actually reading @Sprotte's answer I think I misunderstood the question, I will leave this up just in case however

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreatePizza(Name, Toppings) {
  this.n = Name;
  this.t = Toppings;
  this.load = function loadpizza() {
    //function that i want to be called
  }
  var self = this;
  this.create = function button() {
    var thediv = document.createElement("div");
    thediv.onclick = function() {
      self.load()
    }
  }
}
```